# Avoid creating installation directory for patch installation

Tags: install4j

Today I need a solution to avoid creating a installation directory by install4j version 6.1.3 in a context of a patch installation. I wrote an installer which contains some files to install them to an existing application installation. The files should be bundled together with the patch installer. At the *install files* action i deactivated the *install runtime* selection point but the installer still created the installation directory containing a folder called *.install4j*. In this folder there are only some install4j files. When I deactivate the whole *install files* action the folder will not be created but the bundles files will also be not extracted to the temp-dircetory, right? I also marked the installation directory as an excluded file at the media-wizard. Do I missed something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the "Add-on installer" installer type on the "Installer->Update options" step.

If you need to update the version number, an alternative solution would be to remove the "Install files" action and add a ZIP file `files.zip` on the "Installer->Custom Code & resources" step that contains the new files. In the "Installation" screen, add an "Install content of a ZIP file" action with the "Zip file" property set to `${installer:sys.resourceDir}/files.zip`.